# Javascript: Parse JSON string

Tags: javascript

I have a list

```
 var Names = '["john", "adam"]';
```

I want to remove the string to make it a list.

My resultant output:

```
  var Names = ["john", "adam"];
```

Comment: `var Names = JSON.parse('["john", "adam"]');` This should work

Comment: Try and explore `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse`

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('["john", "adam"]'))
```